# Monotouch.. different responses on two machines

Tags: ios5, xamarin.ios

I am following the tutorial here:

http://software.tavlikos.com/2011/10/13/uipageviewcontroller/

Basically, on one machine running the latest monodevelop and the latest monotouch, the code works fine and the app works perfectly.  On another machine, using the same version of monodevelop and monotouch the app crashes out because the pageController.view is null.  So it dies and throws an error when trying to assign the frame size. Any idea why this is happening?

Below is the code for that section. (in the ViewDidLoad)

```
// Initialize the first page
BookPageController firstPageController = new BookPageController(0);
this.pageController.SetViewControllers(new UIViewController[] { firstPageController }, UIPageViewControllerNavigationDirection.Forward, false, s => { });
this.pageController.DataSource = new PageDataSource(this);
this.pageController.View.Frame = this.View.Bounds;
this.View.AddSubview(this.pageController.View);
```

Comment: Here I am! Some more info would be helpful. Are you testing on simulators on two different Macs then? Which iOS SDKs and MonoTouch versions are installed on the Macs?

Comment: Machine 1 is a MacBok Pro - Running MonoDevelop 2.8.6.5, monotouch 5.2.10

   Machine 2 is a Mac Mini - Running MonoDeveop 2.8.6.5, Monotouch 5.2.10   

  I am faily certain they are both using the latest SDK as well, but I will have to check the one having the problem when I get home from work.  

BTW.. Extra cool for the author of the tutorial I was following respond!

Comment: Ahhh..  I feel so dumb  >.<  The machine having the issue had an outdated SDK.  While monodevelop and monotouch were up to date the SDK was not.  I would like to mark you down as answering the question if you will submit an answer!

Comment: Hehe, there is a reason I did not submit an answer. That's because I wasn't sure if you had older iOS SDK versions. However, did you check Miguel's answer for iOS 5.1?

Comment: I did look at the links Miguel posted.  All it took though to get it up and running was update the SDK.  Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2):

The difference in behavior could be caused by a change in order in how the events are raised by iOS.   We found a change in iOS 5.1 [1] where they now raise events during certain methods that previously were not raised until later.

To solve this problem, make sure that you assign your DataSources or other event handlers before you set properties that might raise events, see this blog post for some more details:

http://spouliot.wordpress.com/2012/03/26/events-vs-objective-c-delegates/

[1] https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=3803

Comment: I appreciate the links!  The answer ended up being to update the SDK to the most recent version.  Thanks for your help!